# Feed new ID into script repeatedly

Tags: r, loops, subset

I searched for a solution to my question for awhile but did not see one that I could get working. Basically I have the following situation:

I read a file into a data frame called `df1` that has a lot of id (each id can be in the file 80-120 times), date, and numerical data.

I have a script that does a bunch of caluclations and then exports a csv file with the title as the classifcation I have created, an underscore, and the id like below. Each file only contains 1 unique id but is usually 80+ rows.

```
write.table(df,
            file = paste(unique(df$classification), "_", unique(df$id), ".csv"),
            sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
```

What I am hoping to do is, after I read in the file, get a unique list (I assume this would be a list?) of the id values, and then feed this into the rest of the script one value at a time. So essentially, I would take the first unique id in df1, feed it into the subset function, do a bunch of calculations, and then export the file. Move on to the second unique id, feed it into the subset, do a bunch of calculations, export the file. Rinse and repeat. This seems trivial but I have struggled to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I assume I can put a loop together prior to the line below and then have it loop through the entire script replacing the xxxxxxxxx with a new id each time?

```
df <- subset(df1, id == xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to loop through like this:

```
for(i in unique(df1$id)){
   df <- df1[df1$id == i,]
   ...
}
```